# 'Learn of' vs 'learn off'

Tags: word-choice, expressions, expression-choice

I couldn't find a thread on this, so I'm asking.

When you're learning facts for an exam, are you 'learning of' the facts, or 'learning off' the facts? It is possible that it may be an English or Irish colloquialism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ***[learn](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/learn)*** [something]:

> to gain knowledge or skill by studying, practicing, being taught, or experiencing something
>
> **e.g.** *I learned about thermodynamics today in chemistry.*
>
> to cause (something) to be in your memory by studying it
>
> **e.g.** *I learned the entire periodic table for next week's test.*
>
> to hear or be told (something) : to find out (something)
>
> **e.g.** *I just learned of yesterday's incident.*

[Merriam-Webster]

To ***[learn of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/learn+of)*** [something]:

> to find out about someone or something

To ***[learn off pat](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/learn+off+pat)*** (British, American & Australian English), or ***learn down pat*** (American English)

> to learn something so well that you do not have to think about how to do or say it
>
> **e.g.** *I learned the whole speech down/off pat, so I won't be needing the cue cards.*

[The Free Dictionary]

Though the TFD claims that *learn off pat* is used in American English I have never heard someone say it.

Comment: FWIW, I'm one American who has never heard any of *learn off pat*, *learn down pat*, or *learn off*. Of course there are over 300 million Americans, from all over the world, so I don't doubt that some might use "*learn off*".

Comment: I agree with @Drew.  I might learn a subject until I *have it down pat*, but I would not *learn it down pat*.  And I've never heard *learn off* at all.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes to *have it down pat* - that is a common expression.

Comment: To *learn off* occurs in British English (not in American English) in the idiom *to learn something off by heart*. The American English equivalent is *to learn something by heart.* Both mean to learn something so well that you can recite the anwer "from the heart", from the center of one's being, without using notes or needing a hint or anything. It is similar to memorize, but stronger. Looking on Google, it does appear *to learn off*, outside of the idiom, is used by some speakers of BrE.

Answer (score 0):

**Learn of**, in the US, means to acquire initial knowledge of a subject.

> I've just *learned of* quantum theory, so I've been inspired to name my new cat Schrodinger.
>
> They got divorced already??  I just *learned of* their marriage last week!

*Learn off*, on the other hand, is essentially unknown in the US.